# Hive LLAP throws Unable to process container ports mapping

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

Im trying to get Hive LLAP to run on my server.

My setup so far is: Hadoop 3.31 , tez 0.9.2, hive 3.1.2, zookeper 3.7.0 all from tar files.

Hive on Tez is working. Selects return the expected results.

Now i wanted to get LLAP running so i setup the config files and generated the scripts with:

`hive --service llap --name llap0 --instances 2 --size 6g --loglevel DEBUG --cache 2g --executors 2`

The yarn application is successfully started but in the application logs it says:

```
2021-11-29 13:21:46,390 [pool-5-thread-2] WARN  instance.ComponentInstance - Unable to process container ports mapping: {}
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4360)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4205)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3214)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.service.component.instance.ComponentInstance.updateContainerStatus(ComponentInstance.java:881)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.service.component.instance.ComponentInstance$ContainerStatusRetriever.run(ComponentInstance.java:1069)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So the services is starting containers but i can not connect to it.

Is there any option i am missing or where do i setup the port mapping?

Answer (score 0):

To the point solution of your problem:
[Setup LLAP on Hadoop](https://www.techaeblogs.live/2022/07/how-to-setup-hive-llap-on-hadoop-cluster.html)

Here it discussed how to set up Hive LLAP on the Hadoop cluster eliminating these issues.